# Convergence of $f_n=(1-x)^n$ on different intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n=(1-x)^n$. Show the convergence is uniform on $[a,2-a]$ where $a \in (0,1)$

I found the pointwise limit function $f$ to be $1$ is $x=0$ and $0$ on $x\leq 1$.

If $x>1$ the limit function is also $0$.

Now I showed that it's not uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$ because there isn't an $N$ which works for the whole interval, since I can take $\lim x\rightarrow 0$.

**Now for the main part:**

Clearly the local maximums are attained at $a$ and $2-a$ (in the second, could be negative).

Now I think I need to somehow pick $N$ depending on the $\max \{a,2-a\}$ such that $$|f_n(x)-0|<\epsilon$$

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $N$ works for both $a$ and $2-a$, then it works for every number in the range.

Comment: I need to solve $|(1-a)^n|<\epsilon$ and $|(a-1)^n|<\epsilon$ , but if I take logs, $n \log (1-a) < \log \epsilon $, somehow $n$ is less than, which I think is incorrect, surely any bigger $n$ should work too.

Comment: $log(1-a)$ is negative.

Comment: but then $\log (a-1)$ should'nt even exist (in reals at least).

Comment: In that case you could not take logs of both sides of the equations in the first place.

Comment: Will the answer be sufficient? $\max\{N_1,N_2\}$?

Comment: If I were grading this, I would prefer the whole proof written out, so if you are handing it in, I would recommend you write the proof out.  You might also want to write it out if you just want to practice writing proofs, or if you're not completely confident about it.